# Xcode how do I set this bool from another view controller to no?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have this bool function in my app delegate that I am trying to return to no on a certain view controller. Here is the code I have in my view controller, no error but it doesn't return the bool "switch" to no.

```
 [(Appdelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]switch];
```

Comment: didn't understand what bool do you want?

Comment: you could show your switch function maybe? it is difficult to understand your question this way, are you trying to set the value or get the boolean value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `switch` is a property in your app delegate, you're not assigning a value to it. For example:

```
[(Appdelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] switch];
```

Will compile with no errors, but it isn't doing anything.

The following would set the bool property `switch` to `NO`:

```
Appdelegate* appDelegate = (Appdelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.switch = NO;
```

If `switch` is a method, again your code will compile with no errors, but it won't set a bool in the app delegate.